# Solve this equation for s

Tags: calculus

$  y=\zeta(s)^{1/\text{log}(x)} $, where $ \zeta(s) $ is the Riemann Zeta function for $ \Re s>1 $.

I tried taking the logarithm of both sides and multiplying both sides by $ \log(x)$ but still could not isolate s.

I stopped when I got $ {\text{log}(x)\text{log}(y)} = \log(\zeta(s)) $.

How do you solve for $s$?

Comment: While both $\Phi$ and $\zeta$ have *common* uses, neither is uniquely defined across all of mathematics.  It would be helpful if you could better define your terms.

Comment: Maybe of interest https://mathoverflow.net/questions/72529/inverse-of-the-riemann-zeta-function